# Modified by Community

Tags: discussion, community-user

The frontpage currently has six questions that were modified by *Community*:

---

[image: ModComm]

---

Does anyone know what modifications were made and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This usually means one of two things:

1. There has been an automatic bump. This happens to questions which have positive (or maybe non-negative) score, when they have an answer or answers yet none of the answers has positive score or is accepted (that is, they are still in the "unanswered" list while having an answer). My experience tells me that if there are new answers to questions the system deems similar, then there's an increased chance that such bump will occur.
2. There has been an anonymous edit suggestion that has been approved.

The easiest way is to click on the "modified 2h ago" text, which will lead you to the last activity. If the last activity is something which was edited then it's the latter; if not see about the score of the answers and usually you can deduce the former.

(I only saw two Community labeled posts, and both were automatically bumped.)

Comment: Ah, thanks, I think they were all automatic bumps. Maybe that process only executes every once in a while, which is why I saw several nearly at once.

Comment: I changed 1 to stress that there must be an answer for this to happen; question without answer do not usually get bumped.

Comment: @quid: I'm not 100% sure that you're right about that, but due to the lack of evidence to the contrary, I'm going to allow that.

Comment: I would say at least "usually" question without answer are not bumped, if they were it ought to be trivial to find examples.

Comment: See here for discussion about not bumping questions with zero answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217884/community-user-does-not-bump-questions-that-never-had-an-answer

Comment: @Martin: Great, thanks!