# Updated questions

Tags: discussion, support, bumping, community-user, recent-activity

The following question of mine frequently appears as recently updated question so I frequently find it at front page.  But neither me nor other participants did any revise or edit on this post and its answer.

What is the reason of this situation?

[A curvature description for center condition for quadratic vector field](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277481/a-curvature-description-for-center-condition-for-quadratic-vector-field)

Comment: The site does this automatically, to any question none of whose answers was upvoted.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler  Yes I see, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the [revision history](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/277481/revisions) or the [timeline](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/277481/timeline) of your post, you can see that the question was bumped by the Community user.

You can find pointers to some information about community user in the [corresponding tag-info](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/community-user/info).

In particular, you can check the [user page of this user](https://mathoverflow.net/users/-1/community). And also the FAQ post: [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738) There are also some related discussions on this meta: [Modified by Community](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1636) and [Auto-bumping of unanswered questions](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2999).

Community user bumps posts which *have answers* but none of the answers has positive score. Quoting from the answer "[Community ♦ seems to be bumping new questions more frequently than usual](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184485#184511)":

> Note that the posts eligible for bumping are those scoring >= 0 that have gone at least 30 days with no activity, have at least one *non-deleted* answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that, and no accepted answer (also, they can't be deleted or closed).

I am not sure whether Jeff Attwoods answer "[Community ♦ should discriminate more when bumping unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99672#99690)" is up to date, but it at least sheds some light onto the criteria how the community user chooses which question to bump:

> Right now it takes the top 100 unanswered questions with no recent activity *by views,* then picks randomly from within that group.

Here is a [SEDE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/data-explorer/info) query listing questions bumped in this way: [Questions recently bumped by the community user](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1291695/questions-recently-bumped-by-the-community-user?num=500). (I will remind that the data in SEDE are only updated once a week, so it shows the status from the last update.) If we check how many times was some question bumped by community user, [this specific question is in top 50](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1291750/questions-which-were-bumped-by-community-user-many-times).